# Tzitzis put on a borrowed garment that is later acquired. Take them off and reattach them?

Tags: halacha-theory, transactions, tzitzis, borrowing

From Torah Law, I need only put tzitzis on **my own** four-cornered garment. From Rabbinic Law, I need  to attach tzitzis to a **borrowed garment** only after 30 consecutive days, see [Oruch HaShulchan, O Ch 14 (8)](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%99%D7%93) .

What are the sources that deal with the  law in the following (theoretical) case:

```
I borrowed a garment and attached tzitzis before 30 days. 

Later (a) within the 30 days or (b) after the 30 days, I acquired the garment from the 
owner.
```

Am I obliged to remove the tzitzis because they were only attached to fulfill a rabbinic 
    law  or did the Rabbis give their mitzva the force of a Biblical law and the tzitzis 
    can be left in place.

Related: [Do you attach tzitzit on a borrowed garment? If so, do you later remove them?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7968/do-you-attach-tzitzit-on-a-borrowed-garment-if-so-do-you-later-remove-them)

Comment: Why are you equating "not required" with "not effective?" If you attach them, then it's not a problem of ta'aseh velo min ha'asui, which would be the only reason you'd need to reattach the tzitzit.

Comment: When I attach them, I do not fulfil a Torah mitzva (of tztitzis). Later I need to have fulfilled that Torah mitzva.

Comment: How is this different from having tzitzis on a beged at night, and then day starting?

Comment: No one says the tzitzit are considered non-existent, only that you are NOT OBLIGATED to put them on a borrowed beged, Their is no p'sul in the tzitzit, so they wouldn't fall under ta'aseh v'lo min ha'asui.

Comment: @DoubleAA You mean, **tying** tzitzis on a beged at night, and then the day starting, I presume. Well, I could argue that when you tie them on at night, you are intending that the beged should be suited for the Torah mitzva in the morning, whereas in my case ...

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok No, I didn't. Taase v"Lo Min HeAsui applies even if the strings were tied and then you rounded a corner and unrounded it.